# How can i set a session from a smarty template page?

Tags: php, smarty

How can i set a session from a smarty template page? I want to set a session variable like

```
$_SESSION['id']['error'] = $id
```

i assigned the value of $id using smarty

```
{assign var=id value=$arrayname.2}
```

Now i have to use this value while assiging session variable.
  How can i do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: *Why* would you need/want to set session variables from your templates? That kind of logic goes in whatever control code is invoking the template in the first place.

Comment: i know but i have to use it. Please give me a solution

Comment: Explain why you have to use it? The solution can be ajax request that sets a session ;)

Comment: Sometimes access to PHP code isn't possible - for example, if you're using a content management system that only allows access to Smarty-powered templates. It should be avoided whenever possible, but there are use cases in which this is a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not. Smarty is **template** engine - you should use it for **displaying data only**.
Sessions should be handled inside controllers => in PHP files.

Comment: "Cannot" and "should not" are different. I believe what the question asks is in fact possible with Smarty.

Comment: @JustinRussell I agree.